# Fibonacci in C#

Tags: c#, fibonacci

I want to write a program in C# to show fibonacci series but I don't know what the problem is.

```
namespace Fibonachi
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int f0 = 0;
            int f1 = 1;
            int f2 = f0 + f1;
            int n;
            n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

            while (f2 <= n)
            {
                f2 = f0 + f1;
                f0 = r.Next(n);
                f0 = f1;
                f1 = f2;
            }

            MessageBox.Show("fibonachi" + textBox2 + "fibo series");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the issue? are u getting incorrect results or what?

Comment: i dont get an answer from it.

Comment: The Fibonacci series does not include random numbers.  Though you're just throwing that random number away so why have it at all?

Comment: And how you expect "an answer" to come up if you never display f0,f1 and f2?

Comment: What is this Random object for? At the end you are just printing a textbox object. Please refer to the numerous solutions and questions on this site for this problem.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with f2.. and why do you have a random number generator? You don't use the number you get from it, but you also don't need to 

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the method shown in the example below. You can use `string.Join()` to properly show the array

There are a lot of tutorials explaining recursion out there. Maybe look up a tutorial on Youtube sometimes. Cheers!

```cs
        public static IEnumerable<int> FibonacciSeries(int numOfElems)
        {
            var numList = new List<int>();

            int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3, i;

            //adding 0 and 1   
            numList.Add(0);
            numList.Add(1); 

            for (i = 2; i < numOfElems; ++i) //loop starts from 2 because 0 and 1 are already added   
            {
                n3 = n1 + n2;
                numList.Add(n3);
                n1 = n2;
                n2 = n3;
            }

            return numList;
        }
```